# BootstrapVue - table column label format

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Looking for assistance on formatting my table labels to display as it as defined in the code. Currently, the labels only Capitalize the first character of the word, and it ignores the rest. Any idea how to achieve the defined value as the label display? Currently IP Address is being displayed as Ip Address (notice the lowercase p in IP) when it renders in the HTML.

```
<style>
    .x-table {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        max-width: 20px;
    }
</style>

<html>
    <b-table 
        style="background-color: #FFFFFF; width: 100%; font-size: 8px !important;" 
        id="my-table"
        responsive
        sticky-header="275px"
        outlined
        selectable 
        select-mode="single"
        @row-selected="onRowSelected"
        :per-page="perPage"
        :current-page="currentPage"
        :items="items" 
        :fields="fields"
        :keyword="keyword"
     ></b-table>
</html>

<script>
    data: function () {
        return {
            fields: [
            { key: 'hostname', label: 'Hostname', tdClass: 'x-table', visible: true, stickyColumn: true},
            { key: 'ip_address', label: 'IP Address', tdClass: 'x-table', visible: true}
            ]
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Try your code in the codepen here: https://bootstrap-vue.org/play .It works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming This is bootstrap-vue.

When creating the b-table you can pass the style object in `thStyle` property.

You can force the headers to be of normal style with `text-transform: none;`.

Read the documentation here: [Bootstrap vue - b-table](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table)

Refer the "Field definition reference" section

Since this is not pure vue, make sure to add the proper tags so that you can reach a more relevant audience.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue. I will be sure to add the additional tags for further posts, appreciate the feedback.